# Unable to update data on a MYsql database from a form tag

Tags: php, mysql

Having issues with updating data into mySQL database. I connect to the database fine and can pull information just fine, but why won't it send information back and store it? below is the php for if the user wants to modify such data

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['Modify']))
 {
   if(!empty($_REQUEST['rep_num']))
   {
     print "Nothing was entered."   ;
   } else {
        $rep_num=$row['REP_NUM'];
        $last_name=$row['LAST_NAME'];
        $first_name=$row['FIRST_NAME'];
        $street=$row['STREET'];
        $city=$row['CITY'];
        $state=$row['STATE'];
        $zip=$row['ZIP'];
        $commission=$row['COMMISSION'];
        $rate=$row['RATE'];
        $error = 0;

        // if($rep_num == NULL ||
        //     $last_name==NULL||
        //     $first_name==NULL||
        //     $street==NULL||
        //     $city==NULL||
        //     $state==NULL||
        //     $zip==NULL||
        //     $commission==NULL||
        //     $rate==NULL)
        // {
        //     print "All fields must be completed in order to carry on!";
        //     $error++;
        // }
        if(empty($_REQUEST['rep_num']) || empty($_REQUEST['last_name']) || empty($_REQUEST['first_name']) || empty($_REQUEST['street']) || empty($_REQUEST['city']) || empty($_REQUEST['state']) || empty($_REQUEST['zip']) || empty($_REQUEST['commission']) || empty($_REQUEST['rate']))
        {
            print "There is information missing from your form.";
        }
        if(!is_numeric($zip)&&$zip!=NULL)
        {
            print "Invalid Zip Code";
            $error++;                   
        }

        $state_length = strlen($state);

        if(($state_length != 2 || is_numeric($state))&&$state!=NULL)
        {
            print "Invalid State";
            $error++;                                                   
        }

        // if ($error != 0)
        // {
        //     echo "<p>The data for Sales Representative ".$num." is displayed below</p>";
        // }

        elseif($error==0)
        {
            $new_state = strtoupper($state);

            $query = mysql_query("UPDATE REP SET REP_NUM ='$rep_num', FIRST_NAME = '$first_name', LAST_NAME ='$last_name', STREET ='$street', CITY ='$city', STATE ='$new_state', ZIP ='$zip', COMMISSION = '$commission', RATE = '$rate' WHERE REP_NUM='$rep_num'");
            $viewquery= "SELECT * FROM REP WHERE REP_NUM = '$rep_num'";

            if($r=mysql_query($viewquery))
            {
                echo "<center>";
                    echo "<table border = '2' cellpadding = '5' style='font-size: 12px; border-color: white; border-style: outset; padding: 5px; text-align:center'>
                        <tr bgcolor='gray'>
                        <th>Sales Rep Number</th>
                        <th>Sales Rep Full Name</th>
                        <th>Street</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>State</th>
                        <th>Zip</th>
                        <th>Commission</th>
                        <th>Rate</th>
                        </tr>";
                            $row=mysql_fetch_array($r);
                            echo"<p>Modification successful. <br />The modified data for Sales Representative number ".$row['REP_NUM']." is displayed below.</p>";
                            echo"<tr>";
                       echo"<td>" .$row['REP_NUM'] ."</td>";
                        echo"<td>" .$row['LAST_NAME'] ."</td>";
                        echo"<td>" .$row['STREET'] ."</td>";
                        echo"<td>" .$row['CITY'] ."</td>";
                        echo"<td>" .$row['STATE'] ."</td>";
                        echo"<td>" .$row['ZIP'] ."</td>";
                        echo"<td>" .$row['COMMISSION'] ."</td>";
                        echo"<td>" .$row['RATE'] ."</td>";
                        echo"</tr>";
                    echo "</table>";
                echo"</center>";
                echo"<br /><br />";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `$row` is defined? or should the be `_POST`? Is error reporting on? Also open to SQL injections here and should update driver to `pdo` or `mysqli`.

Comment: $viewquery= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM REP WHERE REP_NUM = '$rep_num'");

         if($row=mysql_fetch_array($viewquery)){

Comment: had to change from $row to _POST